# Show that property $E$ holds for $F_n$

Tags: logic

$F_n := ((( .... (A_0 \leftrightarrow A_1) \leftrightarrow A_2 ) ... \leftrightarrow A_n)$

I want to show that the following property holds for any assignment $\beta$:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{i < n} \beta(A_i) \equiv n \mod 2 \iff \beta(F_n) = 1$

Now, I tried to use induction, to show that it holds for $n+1$. However, this does not seem very reasonable to me, because even if it holds for $n$, the additional Variable $A_j$ could either be $\beta(A_j) =0$ or $\beta(A_j) =1$, which result in different $\beta(F_n)$.

So is this stillt he right approach? Or should I argue with the structure of the formula?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Induction is fine. Go separately for the two cases.

Comment: with two cases you mean $n$ mod $= 0$ and $n$ mod $2$ $=1$?

Comment: Yes, let's say these two.

Comment: I could try to show for the one case, that if $n$ is even and $\beta(F_n) = 1$, then for the case $n+1$, $\beta(A_j)$ (where $A_j$ is the $n+1$ variable), must be $1$ (otherwise the property does not hold anymore), but then $F_n$ is still true. Is that the right direction?

Comment: Just don't overcomplicate it. No need to distinguish $n$ is even or odd. We have $F_{n+1}=(F_n\leftrightarrow A_{n+1}}$. Just apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Ah so the first case is that $\beta(A_{n+1}) = 1$, then $n$ mod $2$ is still equal to the sum of $A_i$ and $F_n$ is still true. If it is $0$, then the property is not true and $F_n$ is false

Comment: Yes, sth like that..

Comment: Maybe try to post a convincing answer..

Comment: I will do later! Thanks so far